# unable to instantiate activity component info:nullpointerexception

Tags: android

I am getting unable to instantiate activity component info: mainactivity:NullPointerException
My first screen is a splash screen which passes data to main activity.The main activity passes the data to its fragments. This data is used to load the spinner dropdown. The code was working previously when the internet access was done in fragment. Thus, when each time the fragment was selected data was retrieved from server to load the dropdown. But now I simply took the data from server during intial splash screen using async task and passed it via intent to main activity. Using functions like getDepartment() the fragment can access the string.

```
    FragmentTab1.java
    @Override
    public SherlockFragmentActivity getSherlockActivity() {
        return super.getSherlockActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);




        final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
          // Spinner click listener
      spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       // Spinner Drop down elements
      List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
      categories.add("select");


      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        //MainActivity x=new MainActivity();



        try {
            // dept_response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android_db/ppf4_dept.php",response_Parameters);
            //dept_response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://webdev1.tifr.res.in/~PFproj/pplf/ppf4_dept.php",response_Parameters,FragmentTab1.this.getActivity());
            String dept_result=((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).getDepartment();
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(dept_result);
          for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                //categories.add(json_data.getString("dept"));}
                categories.add(json_data.getString("PF_dept"));}


        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
        catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
            }




        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



        final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Spinner2);
          // Spinner click listener
      spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      // Spinner Drop down elements
      List<String> categories2 = new ArrayList<String>();
      categories2.add("select");

     // ArrayList<NameValuePair> response_Parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
             //role_response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android_db/ppf4_role.php",response_Parameters);
            //role_response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://webdev1.tifr.res.in/~PFproj/pplf/ppf4_role.php",response_Parameters,FragmentTab1.this.getActivity());
            String role_result=((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).getRole();

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(role_result);
          for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                categories2.add(json_data.getString("role"));}

        }
        catch(JSONException e){
          Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
  }
        catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
            }


      // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories2);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);




        //spinner3
        final Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Spinner3);
          // Spinner click listener
      spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      // Spinner Drop down elements
      List<String> categories3 = new ArrayList<String>();
      categories3.add("select");

      String desig_response = null;
        try {
             //desig_response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android_db/ppf4_desig.php",response_Parameters);
            //desig_response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://webdev1.tifr.res.in/~PFproj/pplf/ppf4_desig.php",response_Parameters,FragmentTab1.this.getActivity());
            String desig_result=((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).getDesignation();

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(desig_result);
          for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

               // String name=json_data.getString("dept");
                categories3.add(json_data.getString("designation"));}

        }
        catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
        catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
            }

      // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories3);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner3.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
```

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnSuggestionListener {
//***********************************************************************************************************

// start of actionbarsherlock tabnavigation
// Declare Variables
ActionBar mActionBar;
ViewPager mPager;
Tab tab;
DBController controller = new DBController(this);
Intent i = getIntent();
String dept_response = i.getExtras().getString("dept_response");
String role_response = i.getExtras().getString("role_response");
String desig_response = i.getExtras().getString("desig_response");
public String getDepartment(){
       return this.dept_response;
     }
public String getRole(){
       return this.role_response;
     }
public String getDesignation(){
       return this.desig_response;
     }


ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

logcat:

```
01-28 22:24:09.623: D/AndroidRuntime(1123): Shutting down VM
01-28 22:24:09.623: W/dalvikvm(1123): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tab/com.example.tab.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at com.example.tab.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:49)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
01-28 22:24:09.663: E/AndroidRuntime(1123):     ... 11 more
01-28 22:24:15.943: I/Process(1123): Sending signal. PID: 1123 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Line49:String dept_response = i.getExtras().getString("dept_response");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intent i = getIntent();` returns null. You can not use any method of an `Activity` before `onCreate` was called because the information is not set yet.

Move

```
DBController controller = new DBController(this);
Intent i = getIntent();
String dept_response = i.getExtras().getString("dept_response");
String role_response = i.getExtras().getString("role_response");
String desig_response = i.getExtras().getString("desig_response");
```

into `onCreate` because that's not going to work where it is.